# 404 not found with mod_wsgi after set different root path

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I want to load my Django application under different path (exactly, `/beta`), not `/`. After setting a different root path in `httpd` configuration, I get 404 not found error in all pages.

First `httpd`:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/mydomain.biz/public_html/_beta/magnet/django.wsgi
```

and then I just changed the `/` to `/beta`:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /beta /home/mydomain.biz/public_html/_beta/magnet/django.wsgi
```

It seems something went wrong with my application setting but I don't now why.

Comment: Did you really change the path to the WSGI script file as well? That is more than just changing the mount point then.

Comment: Yes, I really change it and it works well because I have some PHP files in `/` and these php files works well.

Comment: So did you confirm that the second WSGI script worked at '/'.

Comment: Yeah, the application with `/` works well.

Comment: Then likely you have/haven't changed some settings in your Django settings file and they are in conflict with it being at a sub URL. For example, have you updated LOGIN_URL/LOGOUT_URL so it knows they are at a sub URL. By default they are hardwire to be at root. They don't automatically adapt when application as a whole mounted at sub URL.